# Altium Designer: Large project hanging

Tags: pcb, altium

I'm making a 64x64 led matrix project. And I have a lot of componets there: 4096 leds, 1024 resistors, etc. So, when I try to import components from a schematic to a pcb file, Altium hangs and crashes after some time.
How I can solve that? 
Thanks

Comment: What has Altium tech support said?

Comment: Running out of memory would be my initial guess. Check task manager to see if memory consumption rises greatly before crashing? If so, some options would be to get more physical memory or increase virtual memory.

Comment: solve it by buying 64 strips of 64 ws28xx-type driven leds, far cheaper and most of the wiring is done!

Comment: @Tyler, I didn't ask them yet

Comment: @horta I have 12Gb memory and Altium uses less than 1Gb

Comment: @Neil_UK Thanks, but leds has to be mounted on the PCB

Comment: Gotcha. I'd head over to tech support then. It's likely they've got a software bug.

Comment: @horta I sent an issue report to them. But Altium's support is too slow and my task should be completed asap

Comment: I imagine the routing is going to be pretty repetitive. If you really need to send a board out today and Altium keeps being bugged, as a workaround I would suggest creating a footprint that combines maybe 16 LEDs + 'routing' in 1 component and placing an array of those on board.

Comment: But adding to that, creating the pick&place files in itself is going to be a though one if only 1 component is used for e.g. 16 LEDs

Comment: Update windows and update altium to the latest version if you haven't already. These types of issues are very frustrating and take a long time to deal with. You will possibly have to try a lot of different stuff, and each step may take a long time. If you are already up-to-date on OS and application software, try removing, say, half of the components to see if that makes a difference. Find out how many you can get without crashing. Sneak up on it.

Comment: One thing worth trying is to disable the PCB DRC checks before importing from sch to pcb. DRC checks take a lot of time to do..

Comment: 12 gigs of memory doesn't matter to Altium, it's a 32-bit application - out of memory crashes are common. Try disabling the online DRC, that may help.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using compile masks to import the schematic components into the PCB in chunks. This will mask out the components from the design compiler, so they won't be compiled and ERC'd, nor will they be imported into the PCB.

Then you can delete the next mask, re-compile, annotate schematics, import into PCB, and rinse and repeat. This way you don't have to delete components, just draw masks over stuff (which is just dragging rectangles) -- it's silly, but will let you chunk up the import.

What version are you using, and where are your components actually stored (Vault, SVNDbLib, etc.)? Maybe you're eating a performance hit from a network drive or something as well. Getting everything local to your machine you can may help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Altium is funny that way.
Best first thing to do is to delete all of your user preferences to get them back to default state.